# C compiler: "Types 'char *' and 'int' are not assignment-compatible" - but there's no int?

Tags: c

I'm porting a FOSS package to HP-UX.  I'm down to one compiler warning I just cannot figure out.  I should note I'm using HP-UX's bundled free /usr/bin/cc, not the add-on purchased compiler, in order to make the package as widely usable as possible.

The compile (which is just cc with no flags) says:

```
Warning 942: "grep.c", line 288 # Types 'char *' and 'int' are not assignment-compatible.
        if ((fname = strsep(&lp, ":")) == NULL)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

fname in that function is declared:

```
    char    *fname, *line, *lp, *ln;
```

So fname is a char ptr.  And that's what strsep() returns:

```
char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim) {
```

strsep is included from OpenBSD: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/string/strsep.c?rev=1.6;content-type=text%2Fplain

So...strsep returns a char pointer, and that's what fname is.  strsep can only return a character pointer or NULL.  So where is the 'int' in all of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you `#include` a header file that properly defines `strsep()`? If not, then the traditional thing to do is assume that the function returns `int`, which is what's probably causing your issue.

Comment: Specifically, you need `#include <string.h>`.  (`strsep()` is a BSD-ism, not defined by the C standard, but when it's available it's declared in `<string.h>`.)

Comment: ABCD nailed it.  Creating a .h and including it fixed the problem immediately.  Very interesting!  I never knew that was a traditional default.  Thank you for the help and the education.

Answer (score 5):

I'd guess that your headers aren't declaring `strsep` at all since it is non-standard, that would lead the compiler to assume that it returns `int` and there's your error. Try adding `-D_BSD_SOURCE` to your compiler options (or isolate that to only apply to `string.h`. If that doesn't work, grep through the system headers (or the man pages) to figure out if there is a prototype for `strsep` anywhere and what sort of macro dance you need to get at it. As a last resort (assuming you have it in your libc) you can prototype it yourself.

Also, I think you can replace [`strsep`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strsep.3.html) with the standard [`strtok`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html) with some modifications to the surrounding code. They serve the same purpose but do it with slightly different interfaces.

Comment: `strsep` and `strtok` are not compatible.

Comment: mu, ABCD beat you to it, but yes, the problem was the compiler assuming the default for a function definition it couldn't find.

Comment: @R..: Almost compatible, they're both tokenizers but the interface is a bit different but you should be able to port it to `strtok` without too much effort. And if you're dealing with something that uses BSDisms then you probably don't have to worry about threads (and if you're mixing the two you'll get exactly what you deserve).